# Can the FFT be employed to make a dataset as Multivariate Normal distributed?

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction

I have dataset composed of a large number of images with a large size (i.e., 32x32px), and I'm trying to adapt a feature extraction framework which assumes that the input dataset is Multivariate Normal distributed.

My question is: is applying a 2D-FFT to the whole dataset a good way to transform the data-distribution to a Multivariate Normal (by Central Limit Theorem arguments)?

In other words, if $X$ is an image of the data-set, I want that its transformation $\tilde{X}$ is such that $\tilde{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{1024}$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{1024\times1024}$.

If not, is there another possible way to do that?

Comment: What does it mean multivariate in this context? Do you mean each image is sampled from a Gaussian Distribution of dimensions 1024?

Comment: Yes, I added some details to the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In statistics there are several transforms which tries to convert data into Gaussian Distribution.
They are called [Power Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) with [Box Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) being the most known.

There is also the [Variance Stabilizing Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation) (VST) which is usually used in the context of denoising (See [Anscombe Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform) for Poisson noise).

The Fourier Transform, being a linear operation, doesn't do that.
What you can say, if the data is Gaussian Vector then the DFT will also have Gaussian Distorbution.